# SSIS changes SQL Server source data type from date to WSTR

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, date, type-conversion

I want to work with a table from SQL Server in an SSIS data flow. One of the columns of the table is `date` type. When I import it to SSIS using OLE DB source component, SSIS changes the metadata of this column to `WSTR`.

Do you have any idea how to fix it? I think that it never happened before. I know I can force SSIS to change the data type in advanced editor, but shouldn't SSIS "know" that this is `date` type column and convert it into `DT_DATE`?

I use `SQLOLEDB.1` as the provider. It's SQL Server 2012 and the data type of the column is just `date`.

Answer (score 6):

You are using `SQLOLEDB.1` which is a pre-SQL 2008 version of the driver (and deprecated), and the [`date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) data type was introduced in SQL 2008.

I suspect the provider isn't detecting the data type as it should, and you should probably switch to the more recent SQL Native client provider.

To illustrate this point, I created an SSIS package with OLE DB connection managers using both SQLNCLI11.1 and SQLOLEDB.1. The Data Flows will both use a  query of `SELECT CAST('2017-02-27' AS date) AS DateType;`

Looking at the metadata, we see SQLNCLI correctly determines the date datatypes

[image: SQLNCLI]

The SQLOLEDB is unable to determine the date datatype and falls back to the "safe" type of unicode string

[image: SQLOLEDB]